# Codeigniter multi_select JSON

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I have a form in a dialog in which I ask the user in which championship he wants his competition registered in. I do this with a multi select dropdown like this:
(Codeigniter)

```
<?php
foreach ($kampioenschappen as $kampioenschap) {
   $options3[$kampioenschap->kampioenschapsId] = $kampioenschap->naam;
}
// Er moeten meerdere kampioenschappen geselecteerd kunnen worden
echo form_multiselect('kampioenschap', $options3, '', 'id="kampioenschap" class="text ui-widget-content" style="width:300px" size=' . count($kampioenschappen));
?>
```

So the user can select multiple championships.

```
var dataString = $("#JqAjaxForm:eq(0)").serialize();
alert(dataString);
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: site_url + "/reeks_beheren/update",
   async: false,
   data: dataString,
   dataType: "json",
   error: function(a, b, c) {
     alert(a.responseText);
     alert(c);
   }
});
```

This snippet will send the form with json to the controller

```
$kampioenschappen = $this->input->post('kampioenschap');
```

This where I get into trouble, when I alert the datastring .serialize gives all the selected championships but I don't receive them in the controller.

Is there a step I forgot or am I doing things completely wrong here?

Thanks in advance for the possible answers.

Comment: Have you verified that your URL is correct? Try seeing what the actual request looks like by using a Javascript console like Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's inspector.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. 'id=53&afstand=3&zwemstijl=1&startUur=08%3A00%3A00&kampioenschap=7&kampioenschap=9&kampioenschap=12&kampioenschap=13&kampioenschap=17' is what the POST request looks like. The problem is that kampioenschap is not received as an array in my controller. Thanks for that tip, didn't know you look at the request like that.

Comment: Okay? What was the result? Do you see any errors? What's in the response?

Comment: Again, you're not giving us anything that helps. You've already said that the POST data is correct, but clearly it is not reaching your controller. Check if the URL the request is being sent to is actually correct. Is there an error response such as 404 or 403? Is there any text in the actual raw response sent back?

Comment: Yes I receive it in my controller, no problem there. But the different championships are not send as an array so I don't receive them all. Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your multi-select dropdown is not in array notation. You should add the `[]` brackets to its name to define it as such.

```
echo form_multiselect('kampioenschap[]', $options3, '', 'id="kampioenschap" class="text ui-widget-content" style="width:300px" size=' . count($kampioenschappen));
```

I was under the assumption that your problem was your controller was not receiving the ajax request. Maybe try to be more descriptive with your questions in the future. :)